# How to get SUM of column using Entity Framework LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to get SUM of column "Weight" using LINQ and store in list. Following is code of join operation of two columns.

```
var que = (from o in db.OrderPlans.Where(i => i.DemandId == _demandId)
join f in db.Fabrics
on o.FabricId equals f.Id
select new
{
    f.Id,
    f.Name,
    o.Width,
    f.Type,
    o.GSM,
    o.Weight
}).ToList();
```

Comment: You need to apply group by first then you can use Sum operator.

Comment: @sriharsha can you please comment that code?

Answer (score 1):

assuming the code you posted above works and let's pretend you stored that in a variable called joinedList (and that you want the sum of Weight across groups formed by the distinct combinations of all the other fields):

```
var groupedList = joinedList.GroupBy(grp => new {
                             grp.Id,
                             grp.Name,
                             grp.Width,
                             grp.Type,
                             grp.GSM
}).Select(grp => new {
                             grp.Key.Id,
                             grp.Key.Name,
                             grp.Key.Width,
                             grp.Key.Type,
                             grp.Key.GSM,
                             SumOfWeight = grp.Sum(w => w.Weight)
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have a one-to-many relation between `Fabric` and `OrderPlan`: every `Fabric` has zero or more `OrderPlans`, every `OrderPlan` belongs to exactly one `Fabric`, namely the `Fabric` that the foreign key refers to.

It seems to me that you want several `Fabric` properties with (several properties of) their `OrderPlans` and the total Weight of these `OrderPlans`.

Whenever you have a one-to-many relation or many-to-many relation and you want to fetch "items with their sub-items", like Schools with their Students, or Customers with their Orders, or Orders with their OrderLines, you use [Queryable.GroupJoin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupjoin?view=netframework-4.8) instead of a standard join.

```
// GroupJoin Fabrics with some of their OrderPlans:
var result = dbContext.Fabrics
    .GroupJoin(dbContext.OrderPlans.Where(orderPlan => ...)
    fabric => fabric.Id,              // from each Fabric take the primary key
    orderPlan => orderPlan.FabricId,  // from each OrderPlan take the foreign key

    // ResultSelector: take every Fabric with all his matching OrderPlans to make one new object:
    (fabric, orderPlansOfthisFabric) => new
    {
        // Select the Fabric properties you want
        Id = fabric.Id,
        Name = fabric.Name,
        Type = fabric.Type,

        OrderPlans = orderPlansOfThisFabric.Select(orderPlan => new
        {
             // Select the OrderPlan properties you want:
             Width = orderPlan.Width,
             Gsm = orderPlan.Gsm,
        }

        // Weight: calculate the sum of all OrderPlans of this Fabric:
        Weight = orderPlansOfThisFabric
                 .Select(orderPlan => orderPlan.Weight)
                 .Sum(),
    });
```